# How to stop same user by making two call at same time

Tags: php

I want to stop user to make two call at same time. Because if there is two call at same time it create bug in my application and update wrong info. I want it to finish first activity of user and give a error if user try to make two call at same time.

I am recording all user activity in table ->

table **feed** ->

```
......................................................
id   ! user  !  value  !  start !  finished ! timestamp
......................................................
7    !  22   !  100000 !    ok  !    ok     ! -------- 
......................................................
6    !  22   !  251632 !    ok  !    ok     ! --------
......................................................
5    !  53   !  125469 !    ok  !    ok     ! --------
......................................................
4    !  20   !  458962 !    ok  !    ok     ! --------
......................................................
3    !  19   !  124587 !    ok  !    ok     ! --------
......................................................
2    !  17   !  321457 !    ok  !    ok     ! -------- 
......................................................
```

I am recording data this way.

- When user activity start it update : **user, value and start** as **ok**
- when user finished activity it update : **finished** as **ok**

Now i am very confused how to check and stop two request at same time of a  same user.

I am using php and mysql

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to block multiple users accessing single method at same time in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024624/how-to-block-multiple-users-accessing-single-method-at-same-time-in-php)

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig thats something different and not solved properly

Comment: Sounds like a very similar problem to me. The point is: When you create a webapplication, you have to expect simultaneous calls to the same function, because that's just the way the web works. Your approach sounds like a pretty bad idea to me.

Comment: Its a small application not have many user and i am very new on this so for me its big problem how to get ride of it.

Comment: Ok. How about this: You describe exactly what you want to do (edit your question) and then we can try to figure out if there is a well-known approach to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your database, make a column like "alreadyInUse", mark it as true when a user makes a call and mark it as false, when the user will be done. While handling other users, always check whether alreadyInUse is false or not and if it's false, only then proceed further. I would suggest you to use threads and synchronization in PHP, for getting better results.

Answer (score 1):

I am second on to suggest proceed with the threads and synchronization, but don't think you need an extra column as your start can serve the same purpose and will save you some memory also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select for update locking read for example:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE")->fetch_array();

//do stuff

$mysqli->commit();
```

or a named lock:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT GET_LOCK(?, 5) AS feedlock')->fetch_array();

if($result['feedlock'] != 1)
{
  //handle lock error or timeout
  return;
}

 //do stuff

$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(?)')->fetch_array();
```